# Why is TCL causing my pyinstaller app problems on other macs?

Tags: tkinter, tcl, python-3.6, pyinstaller

I have a working pyinstaller (mac) app. When I tested it on another mac it just bounced in the tray and died. On launching the exe file (in show package contents) I get the following error message:
`version conflict for package "TCL"`
`This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly`

My understanding of the entire point of pyinstaller is that you can distribute an app without the user having to worry about any of this stuff- it should just work out of the box, so why is this happening?

Comment: What is your `pyinstaller` line of code.

Comment: Sounds like pyinstaller isn't including the library files, so a different set (probably from the version included by Apple in the base OS) are being used. This is a pyinstaller bug.